# Nginx proxy-reverse won't show the index page of my React project

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl

I'm trying to deploy a React application on AWS using Nginx.

Nginx is working properly, I've set up the SSL certificate and I'm able to access my site with HTTPS and the DNS. The problem is: in my Nginx config file there's a html folder with a index.html saying "Hello" and this is the page that will show when I access the URL of my site.

In /etc/nginx/sites-available I have a *client-config* file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ip-ec2;

    ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

#server {
 #   listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  #  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
   # include snippets/self-signed.conf;
#}
```

The last *server* declaration is commented because on my last attempt to get things working I've tried to add the *ssl_certificate* directly on the *client-config* instead of adding it to another file and then including it (didn't work though).

Here's what I want to do:

When I access my DNS on browser I want to call the index.html of my application. I've tried to add the lines:

```
server {
   ...
   root path-to-build-folder-of-my-project
   index index.html
   ...
}
```

But it didn't work too.

What am I doing wrong?

These are the links of solutions I've been trying to implement:

[Set up Nginx to reverse proxy React, Angular and Node projects](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy-react-angular-node-apps-shashank-tripathi)

[Deploy a React app using Nginx](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjDs_nt3uaAAxXhIrkGHeAWDcEQtwJ6BAhDEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DtGYNYPKTyno&usg=AOvVaw0LfJ8NTOD5kwDVA1Lj3FRu&opi=89978449)

[Hosting a React App to EC2 using Nginx with SSL Certificate](https://aws.plainenglish.io/hosting-a-react-app-to-ec2-using-nginx-with-ssl-certificate-6575b58ea8a8)

I can provide more information about configuration files if needed. Thanks in advance!